# Ionic 4 tabs: How to create custom tabs

Tags: ionic4

I am trying to style my tabs to look like what's shown in the link.

[image: Image showing what I want the tab to look like].

I currently have the default tab style and I don't know how to go about adjusting it to look like what is shown in the linked image. Any help from the community will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my crack at it,

**TESTED ON CHROME Pixel 2 XL emulator** this is important because the variables I used will absolutely look different on different screen ratios. I personally used **411x823** which is the screen dimension on a Pixel 2 XL phone. You will need to handle all of the necessary screen dimension cases on your own through css media queries to get a general solution.

**Initial Screen:** this is what I started with. I started with what looks like the default tabs ionic application. Like what you have. Since we're dealing with only `html` and `scss` that is what I will show.

[image: Starting screen]

`tabs-page.scss` starting file.

```
.tabbar {
  justify-content: center;
}

.tab-button {
  max-width: 200px;
}

::ng-deep ion-icon.icon-button {
  background: var(--ion-color-primary-tint)!important;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
}
```

`tabs-page.html` starting file.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar *ngIf="tabSlot === 'bottom'" slot="bottom">

    <ion-tab-button tab="marketplace">
      <ion-icon mode="md" name="home"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Marketplace</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="friends">
      <ion-icon name="contacts"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Friends</ion-label>
      <ion-badge *ngIf="friendCount > 0" color="danger">{{friendCount}}</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button (click)="openRequestPage()">
      <ion-icon name="add-circle-outline" class="icon-button"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Request</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="notifications">
      <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Notifications</ion-label>
      <ion-badge *ngIf="notificationCount > 0" color="danger">{{notificationCount}}</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
      <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

**End Screen:** This is what you're looking for in a rough sense. 
[image: End screen]

**End result:** this is what I ended up creating from the code I had started with. The solution involves using the `box-shadow` css attribute to give the "negative" `border-radius` styling. And then what you need to do is position your center button slightly above your `tab-bar`. I used this [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/scooped-corners-in-2018/) to guide me. Also looking up how `box-shadow` works helps with getting the specifics sorted out.

`tabs-page.scss` ending file.

```
.tabbar {
  justify-content: center;
}

.tab-button {
  max-width: 200px;
}

::ng-deep ion-icon.icon-button {
  background: var(--ion-color-primary-tint)!important;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%!important;
}

:host ::ng-deep .tabs-inner {
  position: unset!important;
  contain: size style!important;
}

.bottom-tab-bar {
  --background: transparent;
  --border: 0;
}

ion-tab-button {
  --background: beige;
}

.button-center {
  --background: transparent!important;
  ion-icon {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 75px;
  }
}

ion-tab-bar {
  &:before {
    box-shadow: 0 387px 0 300px beige;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -48px;
    padding: 56px;
    border-radius: 65%;
    content: '';
  }
}

.inner-left-btn {
  border-radius: 0 39% 0 0; // create the curved style on the left side of the center
}

.inner-right-btn {
  border-radius: 39% 0 0 0; // create the curved style on the right side of the center
}

.inner-center-btn {
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 35px); // position your button in the center
  bottom: 20px; // position your button slightly above the half bezel
  font-size: 70px;
  --background: transparent;
}
```

`tabs-page.html` ending file.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-icon name="add-circle-outline" class="icon-button inner-center-btn" (click)="openRequestPage()"></ion-icon>

  <ion-tab-bar *ngIf="tabSlot === 'bottom'" slot="bottom" class="bottom-tab-bar">

    <ion-tab-button tab="marketplace">
      <ion-icon mode="md" name="home"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Marketplace</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="friends" class="inner-left-btn">
      <ion-icon name="contacts"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Friends</ion-label>
      <ion-badge *ngIf="friendCount > 0" color="danger">{{friendCount}}</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button class="button-center">
      <div></div>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="notifications" class="inner-right-btn">
      <ion-icon name="notifications"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Notifications</ion-label>
      <ion-badge *ngIf="notificationCount > 0" color="danger">{{notificationCount}}</ion-badge>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button tab="settings">
      <ion-icon name="settings"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Settings</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```